# Get renderer from GraphicalView

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using achartengine for displaying graphs in my application. I want to change the renderer series set when a checkbox is clicked but I'm not able to get the renderer or the series from the GraphicalView.

Do any know any way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that ideally you should build the dataset and renderer yourself. There are a lot of such examples in the AChartEngine demo.
For instance, see [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/AverageTemperatureChart.java)

Dan